# Redirect from Visual WebPart SharePoint 2013

Tags: development, web-part, redirect

I created new SharePoint 2013 Empty Project. I used Visual WebPart. I want to redirect from page to another page. Ex: www.google.com

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://www.google.com", SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, HttpContext.Current);
```

When I run this page I get this error: 
[image]

URL is:

> http://mainsite/sites/mysubsite/_layouts/15/http://www.google.com

How can I redirect to `http://www.google.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPRedirect Utility is meant for internal use mainly -e.g. _layouts folder and other SharePoint specific.

For External links, rather use the more traditional HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

Comment: Thanks @C. Marius. It works fine. I have a new questions. When I create page with custom webpart, redirect is run.  But then when I open page redirect doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: If you just want to use the webpart for redirecting user to other page then perhaps you can use window.location.href="full url including http"  inside a window.onload function